# Recommend me a wireless logitech headset

Tags: headset

There are two I am seriously considering, Logitech UE 4500 and Logitech Artemis G933, but I have no idea how to compare them.

- They are both wireless (a must)
- They are both made by logitech (optional)
- They are both 7.1 (a must)
- They both contains mic (a must)

The reason I like logitech is because I want their universal receiver. So basically I want one universal receiver for keyboard, mouse, and headphones. I do not want a bluetooth one (as another mode is okay). Quality of bluetooth sound is not good.

I prefer the one using real batteries rather than something you can charge. The purpose is for gaming.

Which one should I choose?

Price should be around $200. The cheaper the better. However, if there is a better feature on more expensive one please tell me and I may consider.

For some reason logitech doesn't list ue 4500 at all on it's website. I wonder why.

Comment: Also, ue4500 doesn't have a microphone from what I can tell on Amazon.in

Comment: I thought I am supposed to demand a lot. Otherwise more than a few fit what I want and it's against the rule

Comment: hmm..  You should be specific in what you are looking for yes.  But perhaps you could try wording in in a way that is a little less in the form of a demand, and more in line with a request:  such as you are looking for X, with the following features: A, B, C, D.  etc.  I am not trying to be rude, but the way one asks something can result in more or less answers.

Comment: Actually there is only one qualified product. Logitech G933. How much more specific can I be? Logitech H600 is not 7.1

Comment: This question is closed because requirements are too broad. How can the requirements are too broad if only 1 or 2 product fit the criteria? That is the problem. In what way is my "requirements" are "too broad"?

Comment: You have the answer to the question.  Why continue to argue?

Comment: because many of my other questions got deleted for the exact same issue. Closed as off topic. Requirements are too broad. I want to understand what's going on.

Comment: Maybe it is because of how you ask them, as in the tone you use.  You have a tendency to come across as very demanding, and not always polite with people.  Currently there is not a close reason that matches that, so sometimes a mod may close a question and have to choose a random reason.  Personally, I think there need to be more close reasons, but that argument belongs in Meta, and if you want a Mod view on why this question was closed, you should ask in Meta as well.

Comment: It seems that the official reason why it's closed is different than the real reason. Also I got pissed and my tone looks hostile which piss people off and they want to close me for "some reasons" that's not honest. That piss me off and then everybody got pissed off in some form of mutually assured pissed off situation

Comment: Well, how about you take a step back when you get pissed off, and not post immediately.  When I vote to close, it is due to an actual issue, if there is something offensive with how someone is communicating, that is what the flag system is for (as far as I can tell).  Now, how the Mods decide to handle things, is up to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search via newegg.com yields the following results:

[Logitech G933](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826197104&ignorebbr=1&cm_re=logitech_wireless_headset-_-26-197-104-_-Product)

```
Pro-G audio & 7.1 Dolby Surround Sound
Adjustable lighting up to 16.8 million colors
Flexible wireless or wired connection up to 12-hour battery life
Foldaway noise-cancelling mic
```

Wireless type:  RF

Price:  169.99

and

[Logitech H600](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104624&ignorebbr=1&cm_re=logitech_wireless_headset-_-26-104-624-_-Product)

```
Noise-canceling microphone
2.4 GHz wireless
Six-hour rechargeable battery
```

Wireless type:  RF

Price:  50.00